# Coloring volumes based on original point attributes

Tags: geometry-nodes, shaders, color

I have a grid point field as a result of cfd simulation. Each point has its own col attribute. I am trying to convert this field into a volume and color the volume based on the original attributes in geometry nodes so that I can nicely visualise the results. Converting the points into a volume is not a problem, however I can't seem to be able to keep the attribute. (I get it. The volume does not have the same amount of points than the original but I think it could be solved by distances from the original points)

[image]
When I color the points by attribute it works fine but only when coloring surfaces, not volumes.

[image]
[image]

The same goes when I try to convert the points into volume and then color it (which is ultimately my goal)

[image]

Can anyone tell me a way how to handle this? (or if it is currently even possible?)

**UPDATE:**

Ok so I am still looking for a solution. The closest I got was by splitting the data into separate instances of volumes with specific color that are overlapping its neighbours. Thanks to that the emission blends together creating an illusion of a gradient which works for me. It looks like this:

[image]

Now the problem is the overlapping volumes create glitches on voxel contact. Anyone has any ideas how to get around it? Increasing voxel amount in each volume kinda helps (the voxels are smaller) but it is still not ideal. (it's getting close tho). For example, is there a way to set alternating 'zero' point from which the voxels are created? there would be no face overlap and the glitches should disappear

Glitch illustration:
[image]

Comment: How about using a Point Density texture? The 'points' would need to be converted into a mesh with the colour of each vertex set to be the colour of that point in your simulation. You can then feed the colours from the point density into the volume. Do you have some sample data available in order more easily create an answer that's specific to your situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One potential solution (not using Geometry Nodes) could be to use a Point Density texture to colour the volume. This would require the simulation data to be converted into a mesh with the colour information encoded as Vertex Color.

[image]

I don't know if this is ultimately applicable to your situation but if you can provide more information (and preferably some example data) then I can update this answer to be more specific.

Here's an example after tweaking the Point Density and increasing Light Paths/Max Bounces/Volume to get a better representation of the colours (the lack of volume bounces will significantly dull the colours otherwise).

[image: final result]

Comment: Oh yeah!! I'll look into it, but it seems like this is exactly what I need. I don't really need to use GN, it just seemed like the best approach. Never heard of point density node before:))

Comment: Now the question is. My simulation data are spearate mesh planes filling test geometry along z axis (when I get to it, I'll upload a sample). it is one mesh but it does not have any volume just planes. Do I have to convert them into voxels before in order to make it work?

Comment: Basically it is spatial data, not surface data

Comment: Separate planes are fine, provided they're part of the same mesh; only the vertices themselves are actually required (so don't even need edges or faces, although the faces would be useful to be able to visualise the vertex colours when in mesh vertex paint mode).

Comment: I tried your approach and I am more and more convinced it is what I am looking for. Unfortunately for some reason the point density node wont load the attribute of selected object. I tried both to store it using GN and use that and also tried baking it first. I am sure the attribute is there, I can see it in object data properties but whatever what I do the list in point density node is empty

Comment: Are you using Eevee or Cycles? I know Eevee didn't used to support Point Density.... not sure if that's still the case or not.

Comment: Cycles but it doesn't work for me in neither. I am using blender 4.0, also tried 3.5 with the same result

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I create a new vertex group and use that as a color source instead of vertex color it appears in the list:) you think it could be a bug?

Comment: I have seen it where it doesn't automatically refresh unless you switch out of 'Rendered' mode and back again... could it be something like that going on? It's difficult to say.

Comment: Yes - I've had a bit of a play around and I think you have spotted a bug. I also can't see anything in the list but if I vertex paint without first adding a Color Attributes slot then Blender creates one automatically named 'Attribute' and it works fine in the Point Density texture with source attribute left blank (and I can't change it to anything other than blank - unless I pick Vertex Weight, for example). I'm using 4.0.0 Alpha so the problem might already have been fixed in the 'latest'. However, if it does exist in the daily build you should report it as a bug.

Comment: Ok, so I think I've figured out why the Vertex Attribute list is blank; there are actually now different 'types' of color attributes - it can be either by vertex or face corner and stored as either 32-bit RGB or byte RGBs. The old Vertex Colors used to be stored as bytes against each face corner and the list only permits those same types. The Color Attribute shows the type to the right of the name and the menu arrow at the right of the panel lets you convert from one type to another. Changing it to Face Corner>Byte makes it selectable in the Point Density node.

Comment: You are right Rich:) and it works so big thumb up! Anyway there are 2 more questions that came up. For some reason I cannot use the color that comes out of point density as a base color for principled volume (it's just white). It works only as emission color for some reason. The second is whether I can manage to keep the same colors (they get a bit changed) or whether it's the result of averiging the colors around and there is no way. I can always adjust it by hue/sat/val or sth like that so it's ok, just curious

Comment: Not sure why it's not working with Principled Volume 'Base' - I have it working using Blender 4.0.2. Perhaps it was broken at an earlier release...? Don't forget to attach the Density and include a Multiply to scale by, say, 100. You should set the Interpolation mode to 'Closest' in the Point Density so that it just uses one of the colors rather than mixing. Also, the default Light Paths doesn't include extra bounced in a volume and that can dull the colors a bit - increase Light Paths/Max Bounces/Volume to something like 10. With all of those I'm getting a very similar color in my volume.

Comment: Right I'll give it a try:) I thought the colors are due to emission rather than diffusion but I do not really care. Now I can completely deconstruct the domain of the color gradient that originally was in the simulation results and construct a new one so there is no problem there for me. No idea why the diffusion doesn't work with the colors tho, I have the exact same setup as you do (and same blender version)